# How to start and run a command from git from Command Line

Tags: git, batch-file, git-bash

I want a batch file to run a shell script from git bash without any input from the end user.

Comment: Please state the question clearly, add some more details to the question, also show some code is you have already done something.

Comment: I have a shell script that runs a java file to compile spigotMC (Minecraft Server Software) here is the code of the shell script:   JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25" java -jar BuildTools.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line works for me:

`"\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login "/path/to/script/myscript.sh"`

You could also use the environment variable `%programfiles(x86)%` to get to that folder.

Comment: Just the answer I wanted! I now have a batch file running a shellscript running a jar file!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved very easily with a simple batch file. As long as you have your environmental variables set up correctly you do not need to use the git bash. Here is an example batch file:

```
@echo off
git commit -a
git push origin master
```

Comment: The problem is, I have a gitbash file running a jar file for a new spigot complie (Minecrafty stuff)